# Generating Kotlin method/class comments

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, kotlin

How do you generate comments for your methods/classes? Simply typing:

```
/**
```

And pushing enter does not seem to work in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3

It seems like Dokka has superseded KDoc, but why is there no support in IntelliJ? Or am I missing something?

Clarification: when typing in /** + enter, this gets generated:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

But I'm wondering why the generation of @param and others aren't added (like IntelliJ does for Java). These annotations are used for documenting Kotlin code as well (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html)

Comment: `/`+`*`+`*`+`ENTER` generates `/**\n * \n */` for me in 2016.1.3.  Could you have some plugin causing issues?

Comment: Hi yes, sorry I should clarify it does generate that but it does not generate the @params/@return documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html

edit: added clarification to question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate KDoc for methods in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574195/generate-kdoc-for-methods-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 41):

To expand on @yole's answer and @Charles A.'s comment, here is a full explanation of the preferred format when creating KDocs and how it differs from JavaDocs.

The Kotlin documentation here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#documentation-comments

...says:

> Generally, avoid using @param and @return tags. Instead, incorporate the description of parameters and return values directly into the documentation comment, and add links to parameters wherever they are mentioned. Use @param and @return only when a lengthy description is required which doesn't fit into the flow of the main text.
>
> Avoid doing this:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the absolute value of the given number.
>  * @param number The number to return the absolute value for.
>  * @return The absolute value.
>  */
> fun abs(number: Int) = ...
> ```
>
> Do this instead:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the absolute value of the given [number].
>  */
> fun abs(number: Int) = ...
> ```

Answer (score 27):

The `@param` and other tags are not generated because the recommended documentation style for Kotlin is to refer to parameter names from the doc comment text using the `[foo]` syntax, rather than to document them using explicit `@param` tags. You can check the [Kotlin standard library documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/) to see how this style is used.

Comment: Then why does the [Documenting Kotlin Code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) page have a list of all available tags? Am I really missing something here?

Comment: The tags are available and supported, but not _recommended_ for use.

Comment: I'd have to ask you to link me to the documentation which describes the documentation process as detailed as possible. Thanks!
Because by the looks of the link I posted in my previous comment, it seemed to me that that was what the official Kotlin Documentation recommends to use.

Comment: @Daksh For what it's worth, I found that documentation that is being referring to [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#documentation-comments).

Comment: I checked that link ("Kotlin standard library") but I don't see anything about commenting functions

Comment: Those are two different concepts. Including a parameter between brackets `[foo]` produces a linked text to the content's definition, you can use that with any type, variable, ... which is in the scope. `@param` is used to tag the definition of a parameter (mainly if this is a long definition). So `@param [foo] the parameter that comes before [bar]` would be a typical comment. `[foo]` can actually be used anywhere in the comment, not only in the `@param` section.